# Is there a standard protocol for modifying DLL call functionality in AutoHotkey_L?

Tags: c++, security, dll, autohotkey

I have been looking at the AutoHotkey_L source code (which is C++) with the intention of modifying it to control what DLL calls can be made for security purposes of an application we're developing.  There is a preprocessor directive in the source code that makes eliminating DLL functionality very straightforward, but we still need to make some DLL calls for the purpose of the application, we just want those to be tightly controlled rather than allowing DLL calls to the entire WinAPI.

I'm assuming that preprocessor directive for eliminating DLL call functionality is there because other developers have had similar desires to limit the ability to make DLL calls from AutoHotkey. My question is whether there is a similar method in place for controlling DLL functionality without completely eliminating it. Or is my best bet to dig into the source code methods responsible for making DLL calls and figure out where I can control the parameters coming in to allow only certain calls? I looked on the AutoHotkey forums and didn't find anything helpful.

If it helps, here's a quick snippet how the directive controls DLL calls:

Here's the preprocessor definition from the configuration header file (config.h lines 9-14):

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    #if defined(WIN32_PLATFORM) || defined(_WIN64)
    #define ENABLE_DLLCALL
    #define ENABLE_REGISTERCALLBACK
    #endif
#endif
```

And here's an example of an entry point where the ENABLE_DLLCALL directive controls whether the DLL functionality can be accessed at all (script.cpp lines 7910-7916).  For reference, the bif variable here is a BuiltInFunctionType that gets assigned the built in function being called and is then added to a Func object that gets returned:

```
#ifdef ENABLE_DLLCALL
else if (!_tcsicmp(func_name, _T("DllCall")))
{
    bif = BIF_DllCall;
    max_params = 10000; // An arbitrarily high limit that will never realistically be reached.
}
#endif
```

Comment: The reason for the flag is more likely that when developing the DLL call functionality, they need to turn it off to see if it's causing the problem, or something else.  To my knowledge, about 15 people have ever compiled AutoHotkey themselves.  Modifying the source isn't often discussed.  How does the workflow for the users work?  Are they writing AutoHotkey code directly?

Comment: Correct, users will be developing their own keyboard layouts by writing AutoHotkey scripts.  Basically our concern is to give them as much flexibility as they need in writing their own scripts without including the AutoHotkey functionality that could allow a malicious user to cause damage (deleting files, downloading malicious Internet content, etc.). Our idea was to modify the AutoHotkey source and bundle our own version of AutoHotkey with the application we're deploying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pre-processor directives were added to enable AutoHotkey to be built for x64 before x64-compatible DllCall code was written.  It won't be helpful for restricting which external functions can be called.

To restrict which functions or dlls can be called, you can modify GetDllProcAddress(), defined in script2.cpp.  For example, if all of the functions you want to enable are in a dll that you build, you could pre-load it into the `sStdModule` array and disable the code for explicitly specifying a dll file.  You may also need to modify the switch statement near the top of `BIF_DllCall` to disallow calling a function by address.

Note that even if you restrict which functions can be called, it might still be possible for users to exploit DllCall by specifying incorrect parameter types.  A more secure approach would be to code your own "built-in" functions, even if they are just simple wrappers around specific external functions.